# Программа, Интерфейс

Tags: java, интерфейс, генерация-случайных-данных, generate

Вообщем, дела такие: У меня есть небольшая программка(для практики), которая выдает рандомный ответ на вопрос. Ответ от вопроса не зависит, точнее, можно вписать любой текст и программа выдаст ответ, вроде: "Может быть да", "может быть нет" и т.д. В проге стоит генератор псевдослучайных чисел и операторы if, которые сверяют полученные результат генерации. И если он равен заданному числу, то выводится на экран "ответ". Так вот и сам проблема: Я хочу, чтобы текст выводился не в консоль, а в графическое меню, или всплывающее окно, но не знаю как это сделать. Вот код:

```
private JButton button = new JButton("Press");

private JLabel label = new JLabel("Prigramm");

private JTextField EBox = new JTextField();

public Prigramm(){
    super("Prigramm");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container cont = this.getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 2, 3));
    cont.add(label);
    cont.add(EBox);
    cont.add(button);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Prigramm app = new Prigramm();
app.setVisible(true);

Random r = new Random();   

for(int i=0; i <1; i++){
    int q=r.nextInt(5);
    if(0==q)System.out.println("Definitely yes");
    if(1==q)System.out.println("Probably not");  
    if(2==q)System.out.println("Most likely yes, but it is not known");  
    if(3==q)System.out.println("Probably yes");  
    if(4==q)System.out.println("You have no chance");  
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо вывода в консоль

> System.out.println("Definitely yes");

Выводить это так в диалоговое окно

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Definitely yes");`

Comment: Да, но как сделать так, чтобы выводилось рандомная фраза?

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Только после того, как я отправил комментарий дошло.)

Comment: Если помогло, можете отметить ответ за правильный, мне будет приятно))